# create mysql database inno setup returns error code 1

Tags: mysql, installation, inno-setup

I am using the script below to install mysql with my application, but it always fails to create the database and load the database script. The debugger returns an error code of 1, I dont find any other message as regards the cause of the failure anywhere

when i check event viewer, it saw service successfully created and started, which is true, but I dont understand why the database is not created.

```
[Run]
;------------------install service MySQL --------------------------------
;Filename: "{app}\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe"; Parameters: "--install"; WorkingDir: "{app}\mysql\bin";  StatusMsg: "Installing the MySQL";  Description: "Installing MySQL";  Flags: runhidden; Check: MySQL_Is;
Filename: msiexec; Parameters: "/i ""{app}\mysql-5.5.11-win32.msi"" /qn INSTALLDIR=""{app}\mysql"" DATADIR=""{app}\mysql\data"" "; WorkingDir:{app}; StatusMsg: Please wait while we install;  Flags: runhidden

;---------------------CONFIGURING ----------------------------
Filename: {app}\mysql\bin\MySQLInstanceConfig.exe; Parameters:"-i -q ""-l{app}\mysql\mysql_install_log.txt"" ""-nMySQL Server 5.5"" ""-p{app}\mysql"" -v5.5.23 ""-t{app}\mysql\my-template.ini"" ""-c{app}\mysql\mysql.ini"" ServerType=SERVER DatabaseType=MIXED Port=3311 StrictMode=yes ConnectionCount=15 Charset=utf8 ServiceName=MySQL55 AddBinToPath=yes RootPassword=root4u SkipNetworking=no"; WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: Configuring MySQL services; Description: Configuring MySQL Service; Flags: runhidden  


;--------------------- load Database script

;Filename: "{app}\mysql\bin\mysql.exe"; Parameters: "-u root -proot4u -h localhost -e ""source {app}\items_db.sql"""; WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: Loading Database Initial Data; Flags: runhidden waituntilterminated;

Filename: {app}\{#AppExeName}; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,{#AppName}}; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

[UninstallRun]
Filename: {sys}\net.exe; Parameters: "stop ""MySQL55"""; StatusMsg: "Stopping MySQL Service ..."; Flags: runhidden;
Filename: "{app}\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe"; Parameters: "remove ""MySQL55"""; StatusMsg: "Deleting MySQL Service  ..."; Flags: runhidden;
Filename: msiexec; Parameters: "/x ""{app}\mysql-5.5.11-win32.msi"" ";
```

=========================The database script==============

```
/* Tables */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS clothes;

CREATE TABLE clothes (
  id    int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name  varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;

Insert Into clothes (Id,Name) values (1,"Shirt");
```

Comment: Please stop posting these bad questions. This is the third one in a row. Neither of the times, you have bothered to test running the command standalone and checking the results. Both previous question had actually nothing to do with Inno Setup. Both times, it was the command or its inputs that were bad. Had you run the command standalone, you would see the error messages or other indications of problem.

Comment: it would have been easier to point it out that it is a command error, and point that out. If I have the answer, do you think i would ask?

Comment: You should ask only after you actually test the command on command-line. What you did not do, as your answer clearly shows. I hope you have now finally realized that and you won't ask yet another question like *"my command does not work in Inno Setup, I do not know why"*, when the actual problem is *"my command does not work at all, and I didn't even bothered to test it on command like, where I would see the actual error message that would help me debugging it"*.

Comment: Also, questions about command-line arguments are off-topic on Stack Overflow anyway. They have nothing to do with programming. See [Where should I ask command-line related questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84219/218578)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after hours of debugging and searching the web, I found a weird behaviour

mysql does not allow backlash in the source path parameter when executing from sql statements from file.

```
;Filename: "{app}\mysql\bin\mysql.exe"; Parameters: "-u root -proot4u -h localhost -e ""source {app}\items_db.sql"""; WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: Loading Database Initial Data; Flags: runhidden waituntilterminated;
```

so i started looking for a way around this

```
;Filename: "{app}\mysql\bin\mysql.exe"; Parameters: "-u root -proot4u -h localhost -e ""source {app}\{code:GetScriptData}"""; WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: Loading Database Initial Data; Flags: runhidden waituntilterminated;
```

and in the code section

```
[Code]
function GetScriptData(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := ExpandConstant('{app}') +'/items_db.sql';
  StringChangeEx(Result, '\', '/', True);
end;
```